# On React hook component unmount, unable to get updated state variable value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

After clicking on "Click me" button my count value is updating. Now I have to Do Something if `count` is grater then `0` before my component unmount.

But I have noticed during debugger `count` value is always `0`. While I was expecting `count` should be grater then `0` if I clicked multiple times.

Please help me, how to get updated value during component unmount. Thanks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
    //ComponentDidMount 

    return(()=>{                        
        //componentWillUnmount
        alert(count); //count 0  
        if(count){
            //Do Something                
        }           
    })        
    },[]);

    useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;        
    });

    return (
    <div>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
        </button>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forming a closure over the original value of `count` when you set up your cleanup function in the `useEffect`. That means that even as the value of `count` updates in the state, the value of count stays as `0` in the cleanup function.

To avoid this, you need to add `count` to the array of dependencies for your `useEffect`. That way, when `count` updates in state, and the component re-renders, the cleanup function also updates with the latest value of `count`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  return (()=> {                        
    alert(count); // this will now be latest value of count on unmount
    if(count) {
      // Do Something                
    }           
  })        
}, [count]); // add is now a dependency of useEffect
```